# Multiply the last two digits

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to convert and multiply the last two digits of a string.

how can I do this?

My formula is (x * 60) / 100

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30)
SET @find = '16,81'
SELECT @find
```

The value of I need is 16,48

Comment: please let us know what you have tried.

Comment: is it always 2 digits?

Comment: your... formula?? what are you even talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's for converting fractional hours to hours and minutes?

Get the last two characters, cast that to `int`, make the calculation, cast it back to `varchar`, append a zero in front, and take the last two characters. That way the result is always two characters, even if it's less than 10:

```
SELECT
  left(@find, 3) +
  right('0' + cast(cast(right(@find, 2) as int) * 60 / 100 as varchar(2)), 2)
```

The input `16,81` gives the result `16,48`. An input like `16,15` gives the result `16,09`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way assuming the right value is always 2 characters.  If not, you could find the comma (assuming there was always a single comma) and use that instead of "2":

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30)
SET @find = '16,81'

SELECT left(@find, len(@find) - 2) + convert(varchar(2), (right(@find, 2) * 60) / 100)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12975)

Assuming you could have more than 2 digits, use `CHARINDEX` to find the comma:

```
SELECT left(@find, charindex(',',@find)) + convert(varchar(100), (right(@find, len(@find) - charindex(',',@find)) * 60) / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30)
SET @find = '16,81'
SELECT @find

SELECT SUBSTRING(@find, 0, LEN(@find)-1) +  CONVERT(VARcHAR(2),CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(@find,2)) * 60 / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
select cast(right(@find, 2) as int)*60/100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30)
SET @find = '16,81'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@find, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @find)) 
         + CAST((SUBSTRING(@find, CHARINDEX(',', @find) + 1, LEN(@find)) * 60) / 100 AS varchar(30))
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12989)